# App rejected from google play console because unable to login

Tags: react-native, deployment, google-play-console

Everything works fine in when I launch it on React Native Expo emulator. I triple-checked the login credential given. And they are unable to log in.

Is the app not connected to the internet when they test it and therefore unable to make a fetch?

The app is also crashing when trying to log in for apple play store testers as well is there anything wrong in my code???

Here is the function called when they click on login. I made their login skip the 2FA aswell.

```
// API LOGIN FETCH - check for valid login and triggers AFTERLOGIN 
    const login = () => {
        if (username =="" || password == ""){
            alert("Enter Username or Password");
            return;
        }
        const data = {
            VRTS25199769848485696858: encrypt(md5(username), encrkey),//user
            ATTS9364664615902560899: encrypt(md5(password), encrkey),//pass
            ATTSV400112542155GRT558: encrypt(route.params.API_KEY, encrkey)//apikey
        };


        fetch('https://york1.a1payroll.ca/api/STUFF', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            body: Object.keys(data)
                .map((key) => encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[key]))
                .join('&')
        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                if (responseJson[0] == "success") {
                    // CONVERTS PHONE NUMBER FOR VERIFY PAGE
                    const phoneNumber = decrypt(responseJson[7], encrkey);
                    const digitsOnly = phoneNumber.replace(/\D/g, '');
                    const convertedPhoneNumber = `+1${digitsOnly}`;

                    // SETS VARIABLES TO BE ROUTED
                    setId(decrypt(responseJson[2], encrkey));
                    setTty(decrypt(responseJson[4], encrkey));
                    setDivision(decrypt(responseJson[5], encrkey));
                    setPhone(convertedPhoneNumber);
                    setBool(true);// TRIGGER AFTERLOGIN API
                    if(bool){
                        afterLogin();
                    }

                } else {
                    alert("Wrong login credentials");
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
               
                alert('Error:', error.toString())
            });
    }


    // API AFTERLOGIN FETCH - checks for last 2FA Verification 
    const afterLogin = () => { 
        if (username =='lcse782'){// check for superadmin
            navigation.navigate("Menu", { // redirect to MENU
                id: id, // assign params
                username: username,
                tty: tty,
                division: division,
                phone: phone,
                ENCR_KEY: route.params.ENCR_KEY, // forward route params
                API_KEY: route.params.API_KEY,
                API_KEY2: route.params.API_KEY2,
                API_KEY3: route.params.API_KEY3
            });
            return;
        }
        const data = {
            RTQSD123445567856GRT550: encrypt(id, encrkey) ,// entid
            ATTSV400112542155GRT558: encrypt(route.params.API_KEY, encrkey) // api key
        };

        fetch('https://york1.a1payroll.ca/api/STUFF', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            body: Object.keys(data)
                .map((key) => encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[key]))
                .join('&')

        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
               
                if (responseJson[0]== 'YAY'){

                    // ROUTING TO MENU OR VARIFY SMS DEPENDING ON DATA RECIEVED
                    if (responseJson[3]== false || responseJson[4]== false){ // check if 2FA Never done on device or last one is >= 1 day
                        navigation.navigate("Verify", { // redirect to VERIFY PAGE
                        id: id, // assign params 
                        username: username,
                        tty: tty,
                        division: division,
                        phone: phone,
                        ENCR_KEY: route.params.ENCR_KEY, // forward route params
                        API_KEY: route.params.API_KEY,
                        API_KEY2: route.params.API_KEY2,
                        API_KEY3: route.params.API_KEY3
                    });
                    } else{
                        navigation.navigate("Menu", { // redirect to MENU
                        id: id, // assign params 
                        username: username,
                        tty: tty,
                        division: division,
                        phone: phone,
                        ENCR_KEY: route.params.ENCR_KEY, // forward route params
                        API_KEY: route.params.API_KEY,
                        API_KEY2: route.params.API_KEY2,
                        API_KEY3: route.params.API_KEY3
                    });
                    }
                }else{
                    alert("Wrong Login credentials");
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                alert('Error:', error.toString())
            });
    }
```

I added

```
if (username =="" || password == ""){
            alert("Enter Username or Password");
            return;
        }
```

so it would not try to encrypt an empty string and cause a crash. But in both cases they used the provided login.

Comment: I found this that has the same "com.facebook.react.ExceptionsManagerQueue" in my log report i am trying it out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74971619/react-native-ios-app-crashes-immediately-on-simulators-and-testflight-installs